# Duplicate flash gallery with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flash

Is there already a plugin for jquery to re-create this: http://www.imgmodels.com/details.aspx?navbtn=1&cityID=1&modelid=261005&pic=054.jpg&subid=5569&mainsubid=5569&catID=2&indx=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a search on "javascript coverflow" or "javascript imageflow".

Here's an example result: http://imageflow.finnrudolph.de/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at gallerific for jQuery - http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/

You will need to create your own custom css of course, but it's a good start